# JavaScript alert does not give the correct fileID value

Tags: javascript

I have a JSP page that list out files like the following:

[image: Screenshot]

Each file has it's own unique file id and I tried implementing a for loop to get the file id of the files that I "CHECKED" the checkbox.

My JS:

```
function fireGENURL(a){
    try{

        var selectedFiles = $('.fileCheck:checked');


      // var fileID =$(selectedFiles[0]).attr('fileid');
        var count = 0;

        for(var file in selectedItems){

             file=$(selectedFiles).attr('fileid');

            count += 1;
            alert(file+"has been selected");

        }
```

When I ticked on one box, it returns the alert value correctly but when I ticked on two boxes,it returns the alert twice but it returns the fileID of the first checkbox. It returns twice the same ID but my expected result is it returns it's respectively ID.

Did I do any mistake here?

### Edit

```
function fireGENURL(a){
    try{

        var selectedFiles = $('.fileCheck:checked');
        if(selectedFiles.length < 1 ){
            alert("Please select at least one file.");
            return false;
        }

       // var fileID = $(selectedFiles[0]).attr('fileid');
        var $fileChecks = $('.fileCheck:checked');
        $fileChecks.each(function() {
            var file = $(this).attr('fileid');
            alert(file+"has been selected");
        });
        var count = $fileChecks.length;



        $('body').pWin("open", {
            x: 260,
            y: 47,
            height: 450,
            width: 881,
            title: "Generate URL",
            skinMode:'dialog',
            iframe:true,
            url: "file/url/genurl.jsp",
            data: {
                nodeid : file


            },
            offResize:true,
            offMove:true,
            onTitle:false,
            offBottom:true
        });



    }catch(e)
    {
        alert(e);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `each` to iterate over the `.fileCheck:checked` collection, and then you can use `$(this)` inside the callback to reference the jQuery object containing that element. On that, you can call `.attr('fileid')` to get what you want:

```
const $fileChecks = $('.fileCheck:checked');
$fileChecks.each(function() {
  const file = $(this).attr('fileid');
  alert(file+"has been selected");
});
const count = $fileChecks.length;
```

You might also consider using `data-` attributes instead of a non-standard attribute like `fileid`:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-fileid="foo">
```

and retrieve it with

```
$(this).data('fileid');
```

Comment: const is not supported by Javascript

Comment: `const` was introduced in ES2015, which was a while ago and is indeed valid syntax, and is supported by most browsers. Generally, it's best to write in the latest and greatest version of the language and transpile down to ES5 for production so that obsolete browsers like IE can understand it, but for what's going on here, you can just use `var` instead

Comment: Your answer works perfectly but do you mind explaining a little in depth of your code? I couldn't make of it

Comment: `this` inside the `each` callback references the item you're iterating over. Getting an `.attr` will return the value of the *first* element in the jQuery object, so to use `.attr` while retrieving all attributes, you first have to create a jQuery object containing only one element. (or, of course, you could use plain DOM methods for this instead, jQuery only makes this more complicated than it needs to be IMO)

Comment: Then how do I pass this "fileid" to my Jquery `data: { nodeid=file }` ? Because it keeps throwing refenrence id: file not found

Comment: What do you mean? Are you trying to call `.data` again with an object? Use a colon instead of `=` to specify a key-value pair in an object

Comment: perhaps you can checked my edited post to get a picture of it

Comment: `file` is scoped inside of the `each` function, it's not defined outside of it. Did you want to call `.pWin` inside the `each`?

Comment: I placed it outside from my earlier solution because it's able to retrieve `var fileID = $(selectedFiles[0]).attr('fileid');` but since the solution has changed,I should need to pass the fileID I checked to the new JSP page.